# Zapier Trigger: Skipping user entry of an inputField, if only one option is available

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

We have a Zapier trigger, which uses a dynamic inputField for choosing the correct counterpart in our software. When setting up a Zap, the user always sees a dialog containing the dynamic dropdown. if there is only one value available in the dropdown (99% of all usages), the dialog should be skipped. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
operation: {
 inputFields: [
  {
    key: 'blockid', 
    type: 'string',
    label: 'Select Trigger',
    helpText: 'Pick the trigger in your Ultradox automation.',
    dynamic: 'blockid.id.title'
  }
 ],
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That might be possible, but it's not a common use case. Instead of listing the input field as an object in the array, you could instead put a function there. The function could perform whatever request is used to determine how many options there will be and then either return an array of fields or `[]`, depending.

The big kicker here is that `bundle.inputData` **will not** have have a `blockid` value if the user doesn't provide one. Instead, you'll have to do that request again in your `perform` method and supply it yourself.

Hope this helps. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!